# Why we need one min.js or umd.js for our vue UI component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, npm-install, package.json, element-ui

Taking [element-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-ui) as an example, if I want to create a UI library similar to it, a common structure would be to have an index.js file (which includes installation information such as Vue.install) and an index.vue file (which contains the implementation of the component's business logic). To use it, the main path in the package should be set to index.js, and then import + Vue.use can be used.
[image]
[image]

My question is, why do I need to build a commonJS format element-ui.common.js file when installing element-ui? CommonJS is for the node environment, but isn't element-ui designed for Vue projects? So as long as element-ui conforms to Vue's usage environment and its code standard (ESM), why is element-ui.common.js used as the package entry point?
[image]
[image]

What is the purpose of element-ui.common.js? Is it to mount components on the global object before the Vue project loads (perhaps to load element-ui styles before the webpack serve service is fully started)? Shouldn't mounting global components be done on the BOM instead?

If the common.js file is necessary, what problem does this solve logically, is it just for compatibility?

I am a bit confused...

I want to figure out why the entry point in the package.json file of a Vue project UI component library is common.js or umd.js, and why most Vue component UI libraries have both types of files. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: "So as long as element-ui conforms to Vue's usage environment and its code standard (ESM)" - it doesn't. It's Vue 2 lib that didn't change the way it builds over the years. CJS is the way it can be made to work in modular environment, it's supported by all bundlers. It would likely be ESM if they had to start it from scratch. "CommonJS is for the node environment, but isn't element-ui designed for Vue projects" - if package.json and it's `main` entry is read this means that it's Node environment already (i.e. a bundler or SSR process).

Comment: .common.js here is Webpack "library" type output that's built with CJS target

Comment: “It's Vue 2 lib that didn't change the way it builds over the years. ” - So, can I understand that the reason why there are commonJS files is that vue-cli-service automatically adds this file during packaging, “ if package.json and it's main entry is read this means that it's Node environment already” - and because package.json is for the node environment, the main entry to a file that can be run in the node environment?

Comment: Not automatically but because devs wanted this to happen. I'm not sure if it's justified that it's CJS and not UMD like it was done for index.js. That it's CJS allows to keep some things in separate modules but it doesn't seem to help anything here. Generally you'd want to build UMD target for CDN usage, and ESM for bundlers in your lib.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And now I finger out why element-ui has one CJS file. I think it is because of webpack or vue-cli. They will compile element-ui files and put them in bundles. So element-ui lib should have one CJS file.

Comment: I mean that UMD > CJS in terms of usefulness, that's the reason for the former to exist. As for build tools, they would play better with ESM. So CJS is there for legacy reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can some articles help me figure out UMD, CJS, ESM relationship? I have found I am always confused by these standards.

Comment: Don't have one at hand. UMD=CJS+AMD+fallback for global vars in non-modular environment, doesn't need specific support from JS engine. ESM generally replaces CJS but named exports should be static which limits the ways it can be used, while `default` export can be anything which corresponds to how CJS works. For this reason CJS is swapped with ESM `default` in module interop. A modern package is supposed to have /dist/bundle.umd.js (for CDN and legacy usage), dist/bundle.esm.js (for modular usage), /es/*.js (optional, separate ESM modules for fine-grained modular usage where necessary).

Comment: I am confused about the above "ESM generally replaces CJS but named exports should be static". So the "exports" in ESM is not static? Can you explain it?

Comment: ESM exports are static. This refers to the situation when you can do `module.exports[dynamicName] = ...` and `module.exports = anyValue` in CJS but cannot do the same with ESM named exports. See the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export , they are exhaustive.